# Liquibase SQL error -- adds column which is not null to table with existing data

Tags: h2, liquibase

I am trying to use Liquibase to transform one database into another.  I have two databases and would like to run a SQL script on one to make it the same as the other one.  I am using Liquibase version 3.4.1 and two H2 databases.  In order to generate the SQL script I first generate the diff xml using the diffChangeLog command which works fine. (Actually there is one problem: it generates columns which are of type VARCHAR with autoIncrement set to true, but that can be manually removed).  I then use the command updateSQL to generate the SQL file from the diff xml.  The SQL file contains the line:

```
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.USERS ADD ENABLED BOOLEAN(1) NOT NULL;
```

Originally the db contains a table named USERS with two columns: USER and PASSWORD with one row of data (user1, password).  The SQL script fails at that point as it tries to create a new column whose entry for the first row will be set to NULL but the column is supposed to be NOT NULL.  The error is:

> Error: NULL not allowed for column "ENABLED";
>
> SQL statement:
> `ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.USERS ADD ENABLED BOOLEAN(1) NOT NULL` [23502-187]
>
> SQLState:  23502
>
> ErrorCode: 23502
>
> Error occured in: `ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.USERS ADD ENABLED BOOLEAN(1) NOT NULL`

I could try to delete the NOT NULL condition manually, but this doesn't work in all cases as described below.  When I do remove the NOT NULL, this is what happens:

Another related error occurs when the following line is executed (right after the one above):

```
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.USERS ADD USERNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
```

Note that it is trying to add the column "USERNAME", not "USER", which the original database already has.

It gives the same error, and when I remove NOT NULL, another error comes up:

> Error: Column "USERNAME" must not be nullable;
>
> SQL statement:`ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.USERS ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_4 PRIMARY KEY (USERNAME)` [90023-187]
>
> SQLState:  90023
>
> ErrorCode: 90023
>
> Error occured in: `ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.USERS ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_4 PRIMARY KEY (USERNAME)`

Since the column is a primary key it must not be nullable.

Is there a way to fix this easily?  Is there an option in Liquibase which would get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 2):

Add the column first, without the NOT NULL setting. Then update the column for the existing rows. Finally, apply the NOT NULL constraint.

```
<addNotNullConstraint catalogName="cat"
            columnDataType="int"
            columnName="id"
            defaultNullValue="A String"
            schemaName="public"
            tableName="person"/>
```

I do not recommend using the defaultValue setting as it could lock up the table if you have a high rowcount. Very bad for maintenance windows in production.

Comment: This is a good alternative. I hadn't come across the `<addNotNullConstraint>` element before. (I can't help but note your... interesting sample values, though, wherein you're specifying a default string value for an int column. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

When you're adding a `NOT NULL` column the trick is to give it a default value. In your Liquibase XML you'd want something like this, for the column definition:

```sql
<column
    name="ENABLED"
    type="BOOLEAN(1)"
    defaultValue="0"
>
```

That should generate a `NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT 0` clause, as appropriate for the platform.

Comment: But this is functionally different, since it will keep accepting null values after the upgrade, filling in the default value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your database. Mysql/Mariadb can be simple like this:

```
<changeSet author="tibi" id="201803062100-1">
    <addColumn tableName="jhi_user">
        <column name="status" type="varchar(20)" value="ENABLED" />
        <constraints nullable="false" />
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

H2 does not allow this so you need this:

```
<changeSet author="tibi" id="201803062100-1">
    <addColumn tableName="jhi_user">
        <column name="status" type="varchar(20)" value="ENABLED" />

    </addColumn>
    <addNotNullConstraint columnDataType="varchar(20)" columnName="status" tableName="jhi_user" />
</changeSet>
```

or for your case:

```
<changeSet author="tibi" id="201803062100-1">
    <addColumn tableName="jhi_user">
        <column name="status" type="boolean" value="0" />

    </addColumn>
    <addNotNullConstraint columnDataType="boolean" columnName="status" tableName="jhi_user" />
</changeSet>
```